# How to update pom.xml SNAPSHOT dependency version from remote maven repository without touching it manually?

Tags: java, maven

I have already gone through some of the sites these are my findings:
For seeing the new version of the released dependencies use `mvn versions:display-dependency-updates`
For replacing the old release dependencies with new one use `mvn versions:use-latest-releases`

All of them work fine if I have a newly released version. Even we can move from SNAPSHOT to the latest release using `mvn versions:use-releases`

But there may be a case where I have an old SNAPSHOT version 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT but in the remote, there is a new one 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT.

I understand that the first 1.0.0-RELEASE will come after that 1.1.0-SNAPSHOT but I have some test project where I test on the SNAPSHOT version only.

So my question 'Is there any way or any command in maven by which I can update the SNAPSHOT version to the latest SNAPSHOT version which is in my remote repositories without manually updating pom.xml file'.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to this with `use-latest-versions`

https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/use-latest-versions-mojo.html

when you set the `allowSnapshots` parameter to `true`.

Comment: I think that searches for the release version for the snapshot version. By default, it doesn't look for snapshot version next release version. But let me take a look. Thanks for answer.

Comment: So have you tried `mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DallowSnapshots=true` ?

Comment: Yeah I am checking that only.....will comment back in sometime.

Comment: I tried it took the latest release version...my command is mvn versions:use-latest-versions -DallowSnapshots=true

Comment: What is the latest release version of your dependency and what is the latest SNAPSHOT version?

Comment: I found the issue it was the same which you intended to say in your last comment. The dependency was having 1.2.1 as a snapshot and release both so it was taking the release one. I point to a branch that has latest version as a snapshot and there is no release for that. It worked....thanks for staying with me and helping.